# Email dynamic content getting duplicate with first loop value inside foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to send mail to multiple users, Data is not duplicate in my array and it changed in every loop inside for each but the problem is the email which sent to user contain similar info which is coming in first loop

For Example - If array is

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 346
    [request_by] => 43
    [approved_by] => 31
    [request_month] => 2019-03
    [objects] => {"43":{"31":0}}
    [request_by_name] => Q
    [approved_by_name] => E
    [email] => q@gmail.com
)

stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 348
    [request_by] => 35
    [approved_by] => 31
    [request_month] => 2019-03
    [objects] => {"35":{"31":0}}
    [request_by_name] => V
    [approved_by_name] => E
    [email] => q@gmail.com
)
```

first mail will go with the content Q sent an email to E
second mail will be same as first content while the content must be like -
the content V sent an email to E

Please check the below code to check the problem.

```
$email_template = $email_template->row();
foreach ($approvalData as $key => $value) {
    $email = $value->email;
    // pr($value);
    $message_id_hash = md5(rand(1,100000) . $value->email . time());
    $url = base_url()."work/index/$value->request_by/$value->ID";
    $request_by = $value->request_by_name;
    $approved_by = $value->approved_by_name;
    $email_template->message = $this->common->replace_keywords(array(
        "[REQUESTER_NAME]" => $request_by,
        "[REQUEST_RECEIVER_NAME]" => $approved_by,
        "[SITE_URL]" => site_url(),
        "[MONTH]" => $period,
        "[APPROVAL_LINK]" => $url
        ),
    $email_template->message);
    $headers = array(
        "Message-ID" => $message_id_hash
        );
    $subject = "Approve request.";
    // $this->common->send_email($subject, $email_template->message, $email, $headers);
    // echo "mail send from $value->request_by_name to $value->approved_by_name";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving below line inside foreach loop.

Need to reset `$email_template` everytime you send email.

```
$email_template = $email_template->row();
```

Comment: @ihccaman Accept his answer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).